# First line of Dockerfile - what OS?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

Occasionally, I see the first line of Dockerfile as:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

And sometime as

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
```

Assume that I am running Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 and first line of my Dockerfile is  `FROM python:2.7-slim` does it mean that by default all other necessary resource will come from Ubuntu 18.04?

Also, if I am running Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 and first line of my Dockerfile is `FROM ubuntu:16.04`. Does it mean that now all my necessary resources will come from Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: python:2.7-slim has is own Dockerfile https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/2.7/stretch/slim/Dockerfile And the resources will come from the Dockerfile not your OS. It's like a VM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the base image.

python:2.7-slim base image is debian:stretch-slim as you can see in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/00dfb8462f6b3fca152d46b20c0d3b70e8c7ff5b/2.7/stretch/slim/Dockerfile)

So this means that  if you're using the python:2.7-slim image, your dependencies will come from debian.

Containers does not care about the Host OS, if you're running ubuntu:16.04,it means that anything you try to  install on the container will be from the Ubuntu 16.04  repositories.

You can read more about base images [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/).

Answer (score 1):

Each Dockerfile should start with the base image.

It image also has a base image related to the virtualization of the base operating system of the container.

You can check from dockerhub the Dockerfile of `python:2.7-slim`:

- Dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/_/python
- Dockerfile: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/00dfb8462f6b3fca152d46b20c0d3b70e8c7ff5b/2.7/stretch/slim/Dockerfile

In this case `python:2.7-slim` has this base image: `FROM debian:stretch-slim`